# Regular expressions in server_name with Nginx vhost

Tags: nginx, subdomain, regex, virtualhost

I have something I'm trying to do with Nginx. Say I have a few users and a subdomain, and each user has a directory at `/home/dev/sites/USER_ID`. I would like for `USER_ID.dev.example.com` to point to that directory.

I've tried making a vhost files as follows:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name ~^(?<site_id>)$.dev.example.com;
    root   /home/dev/sites/$site_id;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

However, all that's happening is that it's showing the PhpMyAdmin installation I have (obviously another vhost is pointing it there).
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have a feeling it's just bad Regex, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That expression will never match, since `$` is in the middle of the string.  Try:

```
server_name ~^(?<site_id>.+)\.dev\.example\.com$;
```